# PDB not including razor files when debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, pdb-files

I am remote debugging an MVC5 application.  Locally I can hit breakpoints in the .cs files and .cshtml files.  When I debug remotely I only hit breakpoints in the .cs files and the .cshtml breakpoint gives me this message:

[image]

I have checked debug modules window and it says PDB is loaded.  How do I get the .cshtml files included in the PDB files for remote debugging?